# Why is the orientation wrong at app start?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm working on an iPhone app that supports both Portrait and Landscape orientations. When I start the app in Landscape mode and verify the orientation in the AppDelegate it returns Portrait orientation. After I rotate the device/simulator it returns the orientation correctly. It's an iOS 7 app. Anyone know how tot handle this? I need to know the orientation at startup for handling the UI.

Comment: If you want advice on here your going to need to post what code your using.  Also log your rotaions and post.  If people are going to advise you show them have you have done,how you are doing it

Answer (score 2):

`UIViewController` documentation says:

`Note: At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a portrait orientation. After the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method returns, the app uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window.`

That's why it returns portrait mode first. More info in [`UIViewController` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW57).